# C program giving 2 different outputs when running the code

Tags: c

I have a program that simulates a modified version of the Round Robin scheduling algorithm. While the program works fine when compiled on Windows using GCC, it gives me 2 different set of outputs on Linux every time I run it. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Struct to contain information for each process
typedef struct Processes {
    int burstT, remainingT, turnAroundT, waitT;
} Process;

int main(void) {
    // Input data
    int burstT[] = {5, 6, 7, 9, 2, 3};
    int timeSlice = 3;

    // Varible delcaration
    int nProcess, totalBurst, maxBurst, totalWait = 0, totalTAT = 0, sjfCount = 0, rrCount = 0;
    float threshold, elapsedT = 0;

    // Calculate the number of processes
    nProcess = (int)(sizeof(burstT) / sizeof(burstT[0]));

    // Array to store all processes
    Process processArray[nProcess];

    // Array of pointers for SJF and RR queues
    Process *sjfQueue[nProcess], *rrQueue[nProcess];

    // Add all processes to the array and calculate the total burst time
    for (int i = 0; i < nProcess; ++i) {
        Process temp;
        temp.burstT = burstT[i];
        temp.remainingT = burstT[i];
        processArray[i] = temp;
        totalBurst += burstT[i];
    }

    // Calculate the threshold value (average burst time)
    threshold = totalBurst / (float)nProcess;

    // Check process burst time against threshold to determine which algorithm to apply
    for (int i = 0; i < nProcess; ++i) {
        if (burstT[i] <= threshold) 
            sjfQueue[sjfCount++] = &processArray[i];
        else 
            rrQueue[rrCount++] = &processArray[i];
    }

    // Sort SJF queue in ascending order according to burst time
    for (int i = 0; i < sjfCount; ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < sjfCount; ++j) {
            if (sjfQueue[i]->burstT > sjfQueue[j]->burstT) {
                Process *temp = sjfQueue[i];
                sjfQueue[i] = sjfQueue[j];
                sjfQueue[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    // Apply FCFS algorithm to the sorted SJF queue
    for (int i = 0; i < sjfCount; ++i) {
        elapsedT += sjfQueue[i]->burstT;
        sjfQueue[i]->turnAroundT = elapsedT;
        sjfQueue[i]->waitT = elapsedT - sjfQueue[i]->burstT;
        totalWait += sjfQueue[i]->waitT;
        totalTAT +=  sjfQueue[i]->turnAroundT;
    }

    // Get the largest burst time in RR queue
    maxBurst = rrQueue[0]->burstT;
    for (int i = 0; i < rrCount; ++i)
        if (maxBurst < rrQueue[i]->burstT) 
            maxBurst = rrQueue[i]->burstT;

    // Loop through each time slice and apply RR algorithm to the RR queue
    for (int i = 0; i < (maxBurst / timeSlice) + 1; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < rrCount; ++j) {
            if (rrQueue[j]->remainingT != 0) {
                if (rrQueue[j]->remainingT <= timeSlice) {
                    elapsedT += rrQueue[j]->remainingT;
                    rrQueue[j]->turnAroundT = elapsedT;
                    rrQueue[j]->waitT = elapsedT - rrQueue[j]->burstT;
                    rrQueue[j]->remainingT = 0;
                    totalWait += rrQueue[j]->waitT;
                    totalTAT +=  rrQueue[j]->turnAroundT;
                }
                else {
                    rrQueue[j]->remainingT -= timeSlice;
                    elapsedT += timeSlice;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Print the output
    printf("Number of Processes = %d\n", nProcess);
    printf("Time Slice = %d\n", timeSlice);

    printf("\n\n%-15s%-15s%-17s%-15s\n", "Process No.", "Burst Time", "Waiting Time", "Turnaround Time");

    for (int i = 0; i < nProcess; i++)
        printf("P%-14d%-15d%-17d%-15d\n", i+1, processArray[i].burstT, processArray[i].waitT, processArray[i].turnAroundT);

    printf("\n\nAverage waiting time: %.2f", totalWait / (float)nProcess);
    printf("\nAverage turnaround time: %.2f\n\n", totalTAT / (float)nProcess);

    return 0;
}
```

The first, and correct, set of output it gives is:

```
Process No.    Burst Time     Waiting Time     Turnaround Time
P1             5              5                10             
P2             6              10               16             
P3             7              16               23             
P4             9              23               32             
P5             2              0                2              
P6             3              2                5              


Average waiting time: 9.33
Average turnaround time: 14.67
```

The second set of output is:

```
Process No.    Burst Time     Waiting Time     Turnaround Time
P1             5              14               19             
P2             6              16               22             
P3             7              22               29             
P4             9              23               32             
P5             2              12               14             
P6             3              14               17             


Average waiting time: 16.83
Average turnaround time: 22.17
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: `totalBurst += burstT[i];` :  here `totalBurst` is not initialized.

Comment: A decent compiler will do the job! `totalBurst += burstT[i];` -> **warning : variable 'totalBurst' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]**

Comment: @Jabberwocky beat me to it!

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks for pointing it out, that fixed the issue.